# What's the best way of doing a layout with a searchbar and 4 equal parts in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I want to make a website that has a space at the top for a searchbar and then 4 divs in a layout like in 
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dx00.jpg)

I'm using d3 so the idea would be to represent the data in different ways, but I want the divs to adjust to the window, so something like this:

```
    <div id ="main-bar">
    </div>
    <div id="view">
        <div id="topLeft" class="linked-container" >
        </div>
        <div id="topRight" class="linked-container">
        </div>
        <div id="botLeft" class="linked-container">
        </div>
        <div id="botRight" class="linked-container">
        </div>
    </div>
```

But I don't know how to make them adjust to the window size.

I'm not pretty good at web developing so I wanted to know how could I do this in a simple way. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: People are telling me I should not ask for tutorials, which is true. Anyway thanks for your answers, this is what I ended up doing:

```
        #main-bar{top: 0; left:0; width:100%;  min-height: 40px; height:10%; position: fixed; background-color: pink; }
        #topLeft{top:10%; left:0; background-color: blue;}
        #topRight{top:10%; left: 50%; background-color: red;}
        #botLeft{top:55%; left:0; background-color: green ;}
        #botRight{top:55%; left:50%; background-color: orange;}
```

I will look into media queries so I can better adjust the searchbar cause the min-height property is not doing what I want.

Comment: media queries is what your looking for

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the help section on how to ask questions... you should at least try yourself first. There's a lot of information out to help you if you look for it.

Comment: You should check [bootstrap](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-introduction.php) try to read section about grid system,it helps to build responsive layout.Good luck!

Comment: SO is not the place to come to for tutorials. You need to ask a specific question about a specific problem that results in one specific answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to align the divs in css is with flexbox.
Check the flexbox guide [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

This should solve your problem: Working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsLjr2vs/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="search">Searchbar</div>
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="aside-1">Data #1</div>
    <div class="aside-2">Data #2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="aside-3">Data #3</div>
    <div class="aside-4">Data #4</div>
   </div>
</div>

.wrapper, .row1, .row2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.search, .row1, .row2, .aside-1, .aside-2, .aside-3, .aside-4 {
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.search {
  background: tomato;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}

.aside-3 {
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.aside-4 {
  background: green;
}



@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside-1, .aside-2 { flex: 1 auto; }
  .aside-3, .aside-4 { flex: 1 auto; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {

  .aside-1 { order: 1; } 
  .aside-2 { order: 2; }
  .aside-3 { order: 3; }
  .aside-4 { order: 4; }

}

body {
  padding: 2em; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/wokj8ope/)

```
#main-bar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

#view {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  > * {
    flex: 1 0 50%;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;

    &:first-child {
      background: red;
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      background: yellow;
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
      background: purple;
    }

    &:last-child {
      background: orange;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this uses flex so you'll need to make some fallbacks/tweaks for specific browsers. I'd usually do this with some PostCSS Autoprofixers to help with browser support.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flex property if you want to adjust the size of your divs. Include the below given css in your stylesheet and you are good to go .

```
    #view{
      display:flex; 
      flex-wrap:wrap;
    }
    .linked-container{
      width:50%; 
      height:200px; 
    }
```

You can check the working example in this [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mk0476xb/) .

Also , for more info on flex css property try out this [css-tricks link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

You should learn [Media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), it will be helpful. Resize window to see.

***EX:*** What media queries do.

**Desktop**

[image]

**Mobile**

[image]

Based on question,

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.search {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}

.searchTerm {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #00B4CC;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAF;
}

.searchTerm:focus {
  color: #00B4CC;
}

.searchButton {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #00B4CC;
  background: #00B4CC;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/*Resize the wrap to see the search bar change!*/

.wrap {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 2cm;
}


/* 1 column: 320px */

.autowide {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 98%;
}

.autowide img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .75rem 0 0;
}

.autowide .module {
  background-color: #00B4CC;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.autowide .module p {
  padding: .25rem .75rem;
}


/* 2 columns: 600px */

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .autowide .module {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2.564102564102564%;
    width: 48.717948717948715%;
  }
  .autowide .module:nth-child(2n+0) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}


/* 3 columns: 768px */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .autowide .module {
    width: 31.623931623931625%;
  }
  .autowide .module:nth-child(2n+0) {
    margin-right: 2.564102564102564%;
  }
  .autowide .module:nth-child(3n+0) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}


/* 4 columns: 992px and up */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .autowide .module {
    width: 23.076923076923077%;
  }
  .autowide .module:nth-child(3n+0) {
    margin-right: 2.564102564102564%;
  }
  .autowide .module:nth-child(4n+0) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
    <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
     </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="autowide">
  <div class="module">
    <p><img src="http://ximg.es/60/666666/ffffff&text=1" alt="" />CSS is a plain text file format used for formatting content on web pages. CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet and is used by web pages to help keep information in the proper display format.
      CSS files can help define font, size, color, spacing, border and location of HTML information on a web page, and can also be used to create a continuous look throughout multiple pages of a website.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="module">
    <p><img src="http://ximg.es/60/666666/ffffff&text=2" alt="" />CSS is a plain text file format used for formatting content on web pages. CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet and is used by web pages to help keep information in the proper display format.
      CSS files can help define font, size, color, spacing, border and location of HTML information on a web page, and can also be used to create a continuous look throughout multiple pages of a website.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="module">
    <p><img src="http://ximg.es/60/666666/ffffff&text=3" alt="" />CSS is a plain text file format used for formatting content on web pages. CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet and is used by web pages to help keep information in the proper display format.
      CSS files can help define font, size, color, spacing, border and location of HTML information on a web page, and can also be used to create a continuous look throughout multiple pages of a website.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="module">
    <p><img src="http://ximg.es/60/666666/ffffff&text=4" alt="" />CSS is a plain text file format used for formatting content on web pages. CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet and is used by web pages to help keep information in the proper display format.
      CSS files can help define font, size, color, spacing, border and location of HTML information on a web page, and can also be used to create a continuous look throughout multiple pages of a website.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```